# Flutter - How to achieve a persistent side-bar with nested routing?

Tags: flutter, dart, nested, sidebar, flutter-getx

I am trying to achieve a persistent menu (side-bar) in flutter web. I can achieve that as long as all the pages in the app are directly listed as menu items.
The problem is I cannot get the nested pages (pages not listed in the side menu but open on some button click from inside another page) to open in the "content area".

I have tried a LOT of stuff from Navigation Rail to GoRouter to different packages for sidebar.

I don't know what code to post here.

My project also uses Getx.

With whatever code I have I can open 1st level pages in the content area but the nested pages load as a new page and the side-bar is lost.

```
          class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
        const HomePage({super.key});

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          ///
          final MyMenuController menuController = Get.put(MyMenuController());

          ///
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Side Menu Example'),
            ),
            body: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Page 1'),
                          selected: menuController.selectedIndex.value == 0,
                          onTap: () {
                            menuController.selectTab(0);
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Page 2'),
                          selected: menuController.selectedIndex.value == 1,
                          onTap: () {
                            menuController.selectTab(1);
                          },
                        ),
                        ListTile(
                          title: const Text('Page 3'),
                          selected: menuController.selectedIndex.value == 2,
                          onTap: () {
                            menuController.selectTab(2);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(color: Colors.white, child: const SizedBox() //

                      Obx(
                        () {
                          switch (menuController.selectedIndex.value) {
                            case 0:
                              return const Page1();
                            case 1:
                              return const Page2();
                            case 2:
                              return const Page3();
                            default:
                              return Container();
                            return Container();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                      ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // ),
          );
        }
      }
```

Just in case somebody wants to say "Show us what you have tried". I have tried a bunch of stuff nothing worked out so far. If you know how to achieve this, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you share Getx Controller Code

Answer (score 0):

### To know first

You need first to understand that the `Navigator` widget lists all opened routes as "siblings", when you do have a `Page1` that is a route in your Navigator, you can think of it like it is a child of the `Navigator` when you open another route of that `Navigator`, it is opened as a sibling for that `Page2`.

The Navigator widget is an `InheritedWidget`, which means that using Getx for routing disables the interaction with the `BuildContext`
of it (with `Get.to(Widget())` as an example ), which you need to avoid/not use.

```
              ---> Page1---> Button1 ( that opens Page2 route )
Navigator => |
              ---> Page2
```

### How this relates to your case?

by understanding this, if you have a menu bar in `Page1`, it will not be shown in `Page2` since it is a different route, which is why you get that behavior in your app.

### How to fix/achieve your expected behavior?

the `Navigator` widget is an `InheritedWidget`, which means that to get access to it from your app, we use `Navigator.of(context)`, this gets up the `Navigator` widget that is contained by default in the `MaterialApp` of our app.

for having an app that will always show the persistent navigation bar even if we do navigate to nested routes in the app, we need to create a new `Navigator` widget that is upfront the screen which has the menu bar.

```
                                      ---> Page1 ---> Button1 ( that opens Page2 route )
   ScreenWithMenuBar -> Navigator => |
                                      ---> Page2
```

so when you navigate between pages, always the `ScreenWithMenuBar` will be shown.

Comment: Even if I avoided Getx Routing, I am unable to achieve it. I tried with go_router also. I need the url to change according to the page displayed. For e.g. example.com/page1/nested-page

Comment: @who-aditya-nawandar literally a day ago I figured this out. Will link you to a post of mine where I have my Router and some details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75970205/flutter-gorouter-navigation-not-working. Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: I still don't know the implementation; meaning I am sure if you have implemented what I am trying to achieve. I saw the post, it just has the routing code. Can you share more code? I need to be able to open everything (including nested pages) in the content area while maintaining the side panel.

Answer (score 0):

I am using GoRouter as of a couple of days and still trying to understand some key concepts but this is how I managed to implement a nested navigation.

== Router ==

- not a big fan of having all the routes into one single file ( coming from Beamer where you would set a location for each screen so this part might need refactoring )
- the magic happens in `ShellRoute` as that returns the `RootLayout` where I have an `AdaptiveNavigator` and expects a child that is the screen you want to display
- you basically have 2 navigators hence the 2 keys / state and each handle the state for the navigation and the state of the screen
- if you have screens where you don't wish to display the navigator you need to provide the `_parentKey` to `parentNavigatorKey`
- looking at best practices it seems that top level pages should not have transition animations and only when you navigation deeper => list of records would be displayed without an animation whilst details of a record screen would have `CupertinoPage`, `MaterialPage` or `CustomTransitionPage` where you get to add your own magic
- 

```
final _parentKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final appRouter = GoRouter(
  // debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  navigatorKey: _parentKey,
  initialLocation: Routes.login,
  redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    final bool isAuthenticated =
        context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().isAuthenticated;
    if (state.subloc == Routes.register && !isAuthenticated) {
      return Routes.register;
    } else if (state.subloc == Routes.login && !isAuthenticated) {
      return Routes.login;
    } else if (state.subloc == Routes.login && isAuthenticated) {
      return Routes.dashboard;
    } else if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return Routes.login;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  },
  // TODO => create page not found screen
  // * this is mainly used for the web version when you hardlink to an unknown page
  errorBuilder: ((context, state) => const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text(
            'This my custom errorpage',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      )),
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      // * => shell route for the navigation bar
      navigatorKey: _shellKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return RootLayout(child: child);
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: 'dashboard',
          path: Routes.dashboard,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const DashboardPage(),
          ),
        ),
        // * => documents route + sub routes
        GoRoute(
          name: 'documents',
          path: Routes.documents,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const DocumentsPage(),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
              name: 'documentsView',
              path: Routes.documentsView,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: ViewDocumentPage(
                  documentUid: state.params['documentUid'] as String,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
              name: 'documentsEdit',
              path: Routes.documentsEdit,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: EditDocumentPage(
                  documentUid: state.params['documentUid'] as String,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
              name: 'documentsAdd',
              path: Routes.documentsAdd,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: const AddDocumentPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // * => websites route + sub routes
        GoRoute(
          name: 'websites',
          path: Routes.websites,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const WebsitesPage(),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
              name: 'websitesAdd',
              path: Routes.websitesAdd,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: const AddWebsitePage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        // * => tasks route + sub routes
        GoRoute(
          name: 'tasks',
          path: Routes.tasks,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const ListTasksPage(),
          ),
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
              name: 'tasksAdd',
              path: Routes.tasksAdd,
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
                key: state.pageKey,
                child: const AddTaskPage(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    // * => Auth
    GoRoute(
      name: 'login',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.login,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const LoginPage(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'register',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.register,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const RegisterPage(),
      ),
    ),
    // * => search
    GoRoute(
      name: 'search',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.search,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => CupertinoPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const SearchPage(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

== RootLayout ==

- `AdaptiveNavigation` simply checks layout size and if Desktop it will display a `NavigationRail` or Mobile `BottomNavigationBar`
- `_Switcher` is just a class that provides some basic animation when the layout size changes
- 

```
class RootLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootLayout({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

      final Widget child;
      static const _switcherKey = ValueKey('switcherKey');
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return AdaptiveNavigation(
          child: _Switcher(
            key: _switcherKey,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class _Switcher extends StatelessWidget {
      final Widget child;
    
      const _Switcher({
        required this.child,
        super.key,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return UniversalPlatform.isDesktop
        ? child : AnimatedSwitcher(
        key: key,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        switchInCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        switchOutCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        child: child,
        );
      }
    }
```

Overall what is happening here is one router with 2 states that has as root a widget with a navbar and a child Widget that is being passed down from GoRouter.
Please let me know if you require any further details.

Comment: I cannot understand this. Its probably too complicated for me. I just want a simple side navbar that is persistent across all pages including any nested pages.

Comment: how do you push another page in this?