# Flutter - GoRouter Navigation not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have been experimenting with GoRouter and ShellRouter. With the current configuration apart from the redirect to the Login page after a successful Auth has been performed no other navigation works. I have tried to add the routerConfig to the MaterialApp but still the same results. Also I get no errors across the application. Been trying to understand the ShellRouter and I have a feeling its related with how I set those keys?

-- update --

After further investigation it seems that everytime you go or push a new route the entire GoRouter gets rebuild and with this `redirect` gets triggered again. Due to the fact that GoRouter does not have any proper Guards features `redirect` needs to be handled properly.

====================

```
MaterialApp.router(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  title: 'iHub',
                  theme: theme.light(settings.value.sourceColor),
                  darkTheme: theme.dark(settings.value.sourceColor),
                  themeMode: theme.themeMode(),
                  routerDelegate: appRouter.routerDelegate,
                  routeInformationProvider: appRouter.routeInformationProvider,
                  routeInformationParser: appRouter.routeInformationParser,
                ),
              );
```

========================

```
final _parentKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final appRouter = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: Routes.login,
  redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    final bool isAuthenticated =
        context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().isAuthenticated;
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return Routes.login;
    } else {
      return Routes.dashboard;
    }
  },
  navigatorKey: _parentKey,
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      // * => shell route for the navigation bar
      navigatorKey: _shellKey,
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return RootLayout(child: child);
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: 'dashboard',
          path: Routes.dashboard,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const DashboardPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'documents',
          path: Routes.documentsList,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const DocumentsPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'websites',
          path: Routes.documentsWebsitesList,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const WebsitesPage(),
          ),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'tasks',
          path: Routes.tasksList,
          pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: const ListTasksPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    // * => Auth
    GoRoute(
      name: 'login',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.login,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        key: ValueKey('login'),
        child: LoginPage(),
      ),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'register',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.register,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
        key: ValueKey('register'),
        child: RegisterPage(),
      ),
    ),
    // * => documents
    GoRoute(
      name: 'addDocument',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.addDocument,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const AddDocumentPage(),
      ),
    ),
    // * => websites
    GoRoute(
      name: 'addWebsite',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.addWebsite,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const AddWebsitePage(),
      ),
    ),
    // * => tasks
    GoRoute(
      name: 'addTask',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.addTask,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const AddTaskPage(),
      ),
    ),
    // * => search
    GoRoute(
      name: 'search',
      parentNavigatorKey: _parentKey,
      path: Routes.search,
      pageBuilder: (context, state) => NoTransitionPage(
        key: state.pageKey,
        child: const SearchPage(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```