# Flutter How to route with a Sidebar

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I'm currently working on an admin dashboard for a web application using Flutter. The dashboard includes a sidebar for navigation and several sub-directories, like adminDashboard/home, adminDashboard/adminTest. My goal is to enable navigation through these sub-directories using the sidebar, without losing the sidebar's state or causing it to rebuild with every navigation action.

An important constraint in my project is that I cannot directly utilize the ShellRoute concept from the Go-Router package, as the sidebar is exclusive to the admin dashboard and should not be visible on the regular website pages. This has made the navigation setup more complex. (Like in this Post already suggested: [Flutter - How to achieve a persistent side-bar with nested routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75949092/flutter-how-to-achieve-a-persistent-side-bar-with-nested-routing))

The issue I'm facing is that whenever I try to navigate between sub-directories using the sidebar, one of two things happens:

The sidebar disappears upon navigation, likely due to a full page reload, or
The sidebar gets rebuilt every time, which not only affects performance but also leads to loss of its state.

I envision the ideal behaviour as having a "left" part of the screen (the sidebar) that remains constant, and a "right" part of the screen where the main content changes based on the navigation. This way, only the right part of the screen should be updated during navigation, preserving the sidebar's state and avoiding unnecessary rebuilds.

Code Snippets, here I define my routes:

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: globalNavigatorKey,
  errorBuilder: (context, state) => const NotFoundPage(),
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => SelectionArea(child: const RootScreen()),
    ),
    GoRoute(path: '/adminDashboard', builder: (context, state) => const DashboardRoot(), routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: 'adminTest',
        builder: (context, state) => const TestScreen(),
      ),
    ]),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/bugReport',
      builder: (context, state) => const RootScreen(),
    ),
//More routes, where i DON'T want the sidebar visible


class SuperRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  const SuperRoot({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
      title: 'IDC Bugreport-tool',
      theme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

The Sidebar, I use SideBarX:

```
class DashboardRoot extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardRoot({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: MainView());
  }
}
class MainView extends StatelessWidget {
  MainView({super.key});

  final SidebarXController _controller = SidebarXController(selectedIndex: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SidebarX(
          controller: _controller, items: [
//Some Placeholders for the sidebar
            SidebarXItem(
              iconWidget: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
              label: "Dashboard",
            ),
            SidebarXItem(
              iconWidget: Icon(Icons.bug_report),
              label: "All bugs",
            ),
            SidebarXItem(
              iconWidget: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: "Admin Test",
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          // The "right-side" of the screen which should be rebuildet
          child: _ScreensExample(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this type of routing and layout in Flutter? Specifically, how can I maintain a persistent sidebar while navigating through sub-pages in the admin dashboard, without it disappearing or getting rebuilt every time?

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!